# Concatenating Gzipped Lines to Gzipped Files

Tags: bash, gzip, pipeline, io-redirection

I have code that runs something like

```
python extract_info.py -f file.txt | sort -k1 | gzip -c >> gzipped_file.txt.gz
python extract_info.py -f file2.txt | sort -k1 | gzip -c >> gzipped_file.txt.gz
```

Yet when I try to extract information from that file using zcat like this:

```
zcat gzipped_file.txt.gz | python do_stuff.py | gzip -c > output.txt.gz
```

I get this error:

```
gzip: gzipped_file.txt.gz: invalid compressed data--format violated 
invalid input
```

Is there a way that I can append gzipped information to the end of a file that works in a pipeline like this?

Comment: Please provide a reproducer someone else can run to see your problem themselves. According to the gzip specification, your original code should work fine.

Comment: ...and, for that matter, you can run the following yourself: `(echo hello | gzip -c >test.gz); (echo world | gzip -c >>test.gz); zcat test.gz` -- and you can see that it works properly.

Comment: ...so, I **strongly** suspect that there's more going on here than what the code given in the question suggests.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I agree, there may be something wrong.

Comment: I've been running multiple scripts that concatenate information simultaneously, could this be the reason for the bad compression?